# SMTP Outlook Address via VBA

Tags: vba, smtp, excel-2007, outlook-2007

I am trying to retrieve the SMTP Address via VBA for a set of emails in Outlook 2007.
I require the the full SMTP address from the sender. Mainly the address is from an EXCHANGE 2007 server.

I have the smtp address test@something.co.uk; test1@something.co.uk; test3@somthing.co.uk in another table which looks the email addresses to another field.

I need to use the SMTP address from the email to perform a lookup to the field.

When performing the storename = mItem.SenderEmailAddress I get an x400 address, but I need the SMTP address. Surely there is a way of etting this. I don't want to use redemption. I hope someone can provide an answer for this.

Thanks
H

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below, busy using in 2010 though

```
Sub Test()
Dim appOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim nsOutlook As Outlook.Namespace
Dim cfOutlook As Outlook.Folder
Dim ifOutlook As Outlook.Folder
Dim x  As Long
Dim y As Long

'Create a new instance of the Outlook application.
'Set the Application object as follows:
Set appOutlook = New Outlook.Application

'use the GetNameSpace method to instantiate (ie. create an instance)
'a NameSpace object variable, to access existing Outlook items.
'Set the NameSpace object as follows:
Set nsOutlook = appOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

'assign the object variable cfOutlook to the default Contacts folder:
Set cfOutlook = nsOutlook.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts)
MsgBox cfOutlook

'assign the object variable ifOutlook to the default Inbox folder:
Set ifOutlook = nsOutlook.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
MsgBox ifOutlook


y = nsOutlook.Accounts.Count
MsgBox y

For x = 1 To y
MsgBox nsOutlook.Accounts(x)
MsgBox nsOutlook.Accounts.Item(x).SmtpAddress
Next x

End Sub
```